# Make a small launcher image

Tags: python, tkinter, loading, splash-screen, launcher

I want to make a small launcher image that is not resizable, movable and doesn't appear like another open window, for one of my python programs, but after a lot of searches, I still can't find how to do one.
Does someone know how to do this?

I want it a bit like this:

[image]

Comment: What framework are you using for your UI? Just google "splash screen <<your framework>>" e.g. "splash screen tkinter" points you to http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577271-tkinter-splash-screen/

Comment: Ok, thanks. (I am using TKinter)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong about what I think but I think the line of code you are looking for is this:-

```
gui = Tk()
gui.resizable(False, False)
```

^^^
Try this!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple launcher prototype I wrote.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        """tkinter main window init. No title bar. transparent"""
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Self Screen Launcher")
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#0ed145") #0ed145 is Invisible Color
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file="sample.png")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#0ed145", highlightthickness=0, width=self.img.width(),
                                height=self.img.height()) ##0ed145 is Invisible Color
        self.canvasx, self.canvasy = int(self.canvas["width"]), int(self.canvas["height"])
        self.ObjId = self.canvas.create_image(int(self.canvasx / 2), int(self.canvasy / 2), image=self.img, tags="tag1")
        self.canvas.tag_bind('tag1', '<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_click)
        self.geometry(f'+{int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - int(self.canvasx / 2)}+'
                      f'{int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - int(self.canvasy / 2)}')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.lower_window)

    def lower_window(self, event=None):
        """always bottom window"""
        self.lower()

    def on_click(self, event=None):
        """Do something"""
        print("Do something")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launcher=App()
    launcher.mainloop()
```

Be careful with the file path and color to be transparent. I hope this code will help you with your program.